# MERN Stack(Typesctipt Webpack setup) Always throwing error when I send axios request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, mern

Hello guys can I please get some assistance so I have a MERN Stack project and on the frontend, I have configured Webpack and Babel from scratch so I do not know if this is an error from my end but whenever I send back and request to my Node Server I always get back error message can I please get some assistance how I can decipher this bug

**Error that I am getting on the console:**

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    exports http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    exports http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    onreadystatechange http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    exports http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    exports http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    exports http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    promise callback*7929/l.prototype.request http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    e http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    exports http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    Re http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    Ll http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    unstable_runWithPriority http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    Bo http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    Ol http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    _l http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    U http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    onmessage http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    8794 http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    n http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    7767 http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    n http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    3748 http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    n http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    6116 http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    n http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:2
```

**Webpack Setup:**

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlPlugins = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/build"),
    filename: "bundle.[fullhash].js",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlPlugins({
      filename: "index.html",
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
};
```

**.babelrc setup:**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "target": "ES6"
  }
}
```

**NodeJS / Express tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
},
```

you have to specify the contentBase.

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
},
```

so wehpack dev server will serve all the files in dist directory. this will solve the current error but then you will get another error  because you dont have `entry` property in webpack.config.js

```
 entry:"src/app.js" // path to main file of your app
```